# i have an issue in document directory

Tags: swift, nsdocumentdirectory

i have problem when i want to making folder in document directory 
when i making the folder first time like folder (Hello) and when i try to make another folder like (hello) in small letter not anything doing and the folder not creating i don't know why ? but if i try to making the folder (hello ) with small space it is ok and it is display it on the table view i don't know why and if any one can check the folder hello and Hello is different

please help

the following is the code

```
@IBAction func btnMakeFolder(sender: AnyObject) {
   var checkFoundAlbum:Bool = false // for check the folder if is found it or not

    let c = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()
    if folderNameTextField.text?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(c) != "" {

        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        do {

              let document = try fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
                // her i check the album is he exists or not
               let getFolders = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(document, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)

            for folder in getFolders {
                if folder.lastPathComponent!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()) == folderNameTextField.text!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()){
                    checkFoundAlbum = true
                }else {
                    checkFoundAlbum = false

                }
            }

            // her for create folder and display the alert for the user
            if checkFoundAlbum == false{

                let folderUrl = document.URLByAppendingPathComponent(folderNameTextField.text!)
                try fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(folderUrl, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

            }else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Album Exists", message: "This Album Already Exists,Please Change The Name", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (alertAction:UIAlertAction) in

                })
                alertController.addAction(alertAction)
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }else {
        alert()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try this code on an actual device – the iOS simulator is usually not case sensitive assuming the underlying filesystem of the simulator uses HFS+.

Comment: i try it but also not working i don't know why folder not creating in document directory